# Meteor: xlsx to json parsing

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, meteor, xlsx

Im working on a project using Meteor in which i need to do some data parsing from given xlsx file into json. Actually i want some thing like that i upload a xlsx file it gives me data back in the form of json.

Since, Meteor is a nodejs framework so i tried every nodejs npm packages like xlsx,node-xlsx,excel,excel-parser etc etc but Meteor doesn't support the packages' files and gives errors.

So, anybody there who has any hack for this or any solution for parsing xlsx file into json without any issues using Meteor.

Comment: There are packages line https://github.com/stubailo/meteor-xlsx that do the legwork for you

Answer (score 1):

You need to load the package correctly. If you just install the package in project directory like in a plain Node.js project, Meteor will pick it up as source code and try to compile it in its way, which will lead to errors.

The correct way is to use `npm` package.

1) Install it with `mrt`:

```
mrt add npm
```

2) Create `packages.json` with list of Node packages you want to use:

```
{
  "xlsx": "0.6.1"
}
```

3) Load the package with `Meteor.require`:

```
var xlsx = Meteor.require('xlsx');
```

Answer (score 1):

You have made a small application which reads an excel file in Meteor.

You can find it here [meteor-import-excel-example](https://github.com/mlecoq/meteor-import-excel-example)